# Array? args array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, args

I'm working on an addressBook program that reads a csv file and prints the contacts including their lastname, firstname, address, city, state, zip, and phoneNumber. I have been given a piece of code to start with and I have made this part of the code work.

So far, I've read the file and wrote contents to a newFile. However, there is a part of the code which I'm not completely sure what it does. Because I'm new to programming I do not want to just slop together code that simply works, I want to understand what's going on.
The part I'm confused about is right after the main statement
 (the first 9 lines after main begins starting at String [] lname, fname, street.....)

Please, any help will be appreciated.

```
public class Main 
{
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String [] lName, fName, street, city, state, zip, phone;

    lName = new String[20];
    fName = new String[20];
    street = new String[50];
    city = new String[20];
    state = new String[20];
    zip = new String[12];

    System.out.println("ADDRESS BOOK CONTENTS: ");

    Scanner inFile;

    try 
    {
        inFile = new Scanner (new File("src/addresses.csv"));
        String temp;

        while (inFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            temp = inFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Contact:    " + temp);              
        }   

        System.out.println(inFile);


    }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            //catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("src/addresses.csv");
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("src/newfile.csv");

    int c;
    while ((c = fileIn.read()) != -1)
    {
        fileOut.write(c);
    }

    fileIn.close();
    fileOut.close();
    }

     catch (FileNotFoundException exception1) 
      {
         System.err.println("FileCopy: " + exception1);
      } 
      catch (IOException exception1) 
      {
         System.err.println("FileCopy: " + exception1);
      }

}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `lName = new String[20]` ? If so, see [Java Tutorial: Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Amazing nested scroll bars :D

Comment: `<pre><code>`, I didn't realize it would have that side effect.  It's like GeoCities all over again :P

Comment: @hmjd, yeah that's what I meant

Comment: @Maroun Maroun, I suppose I'm doing something wrong, lol. everytime I use the code button provided it never puts all of my code inside so i used the <pre><code> and that's what happened;-)

Comment: @user2044988 You should use ` to write code. I'll use your trick to impress users with multiple nested scroll bars ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those part of the code is an array creation statement.

```
lName = new String[20];
```

Means create a new array of string with 20 elements and assign it to variable `lName`

And just to give you few more array examples to start with:

```
lName[4] = "john";
```

Means assign the string value "john" to the 5th (not 4th) element of the array

```
String name = lName[0];
```

Means retrieve the first element of the array and assign it to the variable called `name`

Comment: Ok, so I would actually b creating a new array for each one of those statements

Comment: Ok so if that statement create an array with 20 elements, then why use the line right before these statements? `String [] lName, fName, street, city, state, zip, phone;`

Comment: That's just to save from typing extra letters in your code. Following statements are equivalent: `String[] a,b;`  and `String[] a;  String[] b;`

Comment: So in actuality, I would be creating a new string array for lName, fName, etc. and then again creating another string array for each lName, fName etc with the next statements, what would be the reason to create both I guess is what I'm asking.

Comment: To make it clear, `String[] a;` doesn't create any array, it only create a reference to an array with value null. In other word `String[] a;` and `String[] a = null` is equivalent.  `a = new String[20]` creates the array on the heap, and assign the reference to it to variable a.

Answer (score 1):

This just declares some variables of type `String[]` which is an array of strings.

The following lines are assigning a new `array` with an initial capacity to those variables.

This syntax declares the variable first and assign after, but you can also do the declaration and the assignation in one statement like this :

```
String[] lName = new String[20];
```

The two syntax are equivalent.

Comment: @user2044988 surround the code with ` instead of writing <code>

Comment: @benzonico perfect, that's exactly what I was wondering (after the fact of what exactly they were)!!